# V-model binding not working on mobile, except if I add an alert

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a very weird issue with my form input binding in my vue app. My input field is an auto-suggest search field with the following syntax:

```
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="search" @input="onChange" @keyup.up="onArrowUp" @keyup.down="onArrowDown" @keyup.enter="onEnter"/>
```

The function v-model references looks as follows:

```
onChange () {
    this.reset()
    this.isOpen = true
    this.filterResults()
},
filterResults () {
    this.results = this.items.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
}
```

It works perfectly on desktop, as can be seen in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/SorenRomer/pen/a3902e39bc957e69e9438ef113bbb83e), but when I try it out on mobile the filtering doesn't happen. It just displays the full results-list regardless of input. What's weird is, that if I trouble-shoot, and try to add alerts to the onChange and filterResults functions, it all of a sudden runs smoothly. Any ideas as to what is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please include a full example. Where is `this.search` defined?

Comment: @kichik: I have updated the link to the CodePen to reference the editor, where the entire code is available

Comment: I think it will work also if click other blank area instead of adding `alert()`. It seems input event is fired when you click the input element, then input is not fired during typing.

Comment: `alert` is not good for debugging as it interrupts the execution. If you have an android phone, you can try remote debugging ~ https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/how-to-debug-your-website-in-android-chrome-29ee031b24e3

Comment: I would move `filterResults` from a method to a computed property. That's typically how I've done typeahead style searches in the past

Comment: The underlying problem is described in these bugs and apparently it's a feature: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8231 and https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8723.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a really interesting one! Turns out de-coupling the two way data binding does half of the trick.

Also noteworthy: key events are not always correctly detected on mobile, overlapping events are bad. The order of execution isn't always obvious when an event fires and sets something in the component state.

I exported your codepen and edited the HTML instead of the pug template to:

```
<input class="input" type="text" v-bind:value="search" @input="updateSearch($event.target.value)" @keyup.up="onArrowUp" @keyup.down="onArrowDown" @keyup.enter="onEnter"/>
```

my first two methods in the vue component are now:

```
    filterResults(){
        this.isOpen = true;
        this.results = this.items.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    },
    updateSearch(value){
        this.search = value;
        this.filterResults();
    },
```

instead of the onChange one.

If you want the working example I'll be happy to zip it up for you, but I didn't just want to put it online since it's a private pen.

Full diff of the JavaScript file below:

```
% diff js/index.js ../jobrisk-calculator_oprindelig/js/index.js 
16,18c16,19
<               filterResults(){
<                       this.isOpen = true;
<                       this.results = this.items.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf
(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
---
>               onChange () {
>                       this.reset()
>                       this.isOpen = true
>                       this.filterResults()
20,22c21,22
<               updateSearch(value){
<                       this.search = value;
<                       this.filterResults();
---
>               filterResults() {
>                       this.results = this.items.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf
(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
49c49
<                       this.setResult(this.results[this.arrowCounter]);
---
>                       this.search = this.results[this.arrowCounter]
```

Greetings from Copenhagen!

Comment: Works like a charm! Tak for hjælpen :)

Comment: @SorenRomer No probs :) held og lykke!